# Return other value in a 2-element set Python

Tags: python, list, set, runtime

given a value in an **immutable** set of two values, how do I access what the other value is?

It needs to be in a set of sets, so I'm not sure how else I would do it without frozenset.

example:

```
myset = frozenset([a,b])
given a, how do I access the value of b?
```

context:
so I'm iterating over a set of sets

```
data = [(a list of lists)]
movies = set(frozenset(d[:2]) for d in data)
for movie in movies:
    ...if a in movie:
       ...other_value = b
```

thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to use a different structure. Perhaps you should explain *why* it needs to be a set.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Since sets and frozensets are unordered, they require conversion to an ordered type, or iterating the whole set.

```
myset = frozenset([1, 2])

a = 1
next(i for i in myset if i!=a)  # 2
tuple(myset - {a})[0]           # 2
list(myset - {a})[0]            # 2
```